# return negative integer to remove from counter

Tags: integer, return, conditional-statements, counter

I have a php script that process data and passes this data to another function 10 at a time in the next script there is a if statement that validates additional info and will break if things dont match so if 10 are passed to the second function and then 10 are not processed due the additional validation the script returns nothing is there a way to return a -counter to the first script if the validation in the second script fails.

```
function first_function()
{
    $i = 0
    if ($i >= 10) {
        break;
    } else {
        second_function();
        ++$i;
    }
}

function second_function()
{
    if ($test != 'answer') {
        return --$i;
        break;
    } else {
        process_data();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do, despite your description.  Do you simply want to return `-$i` at the point where you return `--$i`?

Comment: I increase the counter after the second function is called but sometimes in the second function if the condition doesn't pass the function will break and only a fraction of the 10 that have been passed from the first function will be run. so I am trying to find a way to subtract from the counter in the first function if the condition is not meet in the second function. or is there a way to return the increase to the counter from the second function after it has passed the condition?

Comment: Why don't you just return a `true` or `false` value from `second_function` to indicate success, and handle all the counting inside `first_function`?